# Format a DataGridViewColumn with a comma delimiter for thousand

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting, number-formatting

I am trying to format a DataGridViewColumn with a comma delimiter for thousand and 2 decimal places. 
For example:

> 1500.50 will be converted to 1,500.50
>
> 1500.5 will be converted to 1,500.50
>
> 1500.50015 will be converted to 1,500.50

After setting the datasource:

```
shipmentDetailsDataGridView.SetDataSource(dt);
```

I tried :

```
shipmentDetailsDataGridView.Columns[Glossary.Total].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0.#0";
```

and

```
shipmentDetailsDataGridView.Columns[Glossary.Total].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

But I am getting the following result:

> ```
> 1.500.50 instead of 1,500.50
> ```

I checked the regional settings but it looks defined correctly:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ? Also use "#,##0.00" instead of "#,##0.#0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. So many time wasted.
This was a font issue. I changed the font from Microsoft San Serif to Arial and now the comma is there. Using Microsoft San Serif, the comma looks like a dot.

[image]